# External user access - Portal Super User Access not working

Tags: community, sharing, partner-communities, sharing-sets

I have setup a community for B2B partner users, and a custom object which has lookup to Contact & Account. The sharing set is enabled and provided to provide access to custom object records and the community is enabled with super user access and has only one role(as per SF recommendation to have lesser roles if possible).

For example, I have a scenario where Account A is enabled as partner. It has 3 contacts Person A, B & C. All 3 users are partner users, User A has super user access.

There are 5 records R1 to R5, all records are owned by internal users but shared to external users via sharing set. R1 is shared with Person A. R2,R3 is shared with Person B. R4, R5 shared with Person C. The users are able to see these records.

My issue here is, Since R1 is assigned with super user access he should be able to view records his peers(Person B&C) can see. However, he is unable to see it.

Please advise what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you setup the partner roles for these users as well? [Grant Super User Access to a Partner User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_partner_super_user_access.htm&type=5): `Super users can get insights into the records of other partner users who are at their role level or below them in the role hierarchy. `

Comment: Hi @Raul, Yes all the 3 users has the role in their user record which is 'Company A Partner User'. Just to update one more point, I have tried having 2 roles as well(with user & manager). Both super user & hierarchy was working and Person A able to view all records if the records as owned by portal users. In my case,the record has to be owned by internal user and shared with external user. As per the documentation, it has the super user works for all records owned/shared. Please advise what I m missing.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "Portal Super User" but your license choice implies you are using Partner Super User.

Partner Super User is a role-based sharing mechanism.

Record access granted to users via a sharing set isn’t extended to the role hierarchy.